# Relations between different definitions of critical temperatures

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, phase-transition

I have noticed the following definitions of critical temperature $T_c$ being used in different subject areas:

1. **MAG**: The temperature below which some order parameter (e.g. magnetization or self-overlap) becomes non-zero given some boundary interactions (e.g. +/- spins at the boundary for the Ising model)
2. **LRO**: The temperature below which long range order develops, in the sense the two-point function $\langle \sigma_0 \sigma_x \rangle$ > 0 even when $||x|| \to \infty$
3. **EXP**: The temperature above which the two-point function $\langle \sigma_0 \sigma_x \rangle$ decays at least exponentially (with respect to $||x||$)
4. **FREE**: The temperature where the free energy is non-analytic (e.g. the derivative of a certain order is not defined)
5. **GIBBS**: The temperature below which the gibbs states differ in number or qualitative nature to high $T$

One would think that all 5 definitions are equivalent (at least that's what I thought from physical heuristics), and in the case of the Ising model, they are. But this is not really the case in general. Here are some examples of non-equivalence:

- The most classical example is the [BKT transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosterlitz%E2%80%93Thouless_transition) where the EXP definition does not match the MAG definition. In particular, in the low T phase, the correlations do not decay exponentially, yet there is no magnetization
- At the [Nishimori line](http://web.mit.edu/8.334/www/grades/projects/projects17/PeterLu.pdf) of the ranodm-bond Ising model, the FREE definition does not match the MAG definition. In particular, the free energy of the model is always analytic, yet there is an order/disorder transition for the magnetization.

Given the non-equivalence of the five definitions, my questions are:

- Has it been shown rigorously that at least some of the five definitions are equivalent, under very mild conditions (such as translation-invariance of the lattice)? For example, think the random-cluster model with $q<1$, or the [EA spin glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_glass#Edwards%E2%80%93Anderson_model) in $\mathbb{Z}^d$, or any model without [FKG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality).
- Is there any inequality between the critical temperatures defined above, besides the trivial ones? (clearly $T_c^{\text{LRO}} < T_c^{\text{EXP}}$)
- What are some other interesting models that breaks equivalence of the five definitions?

Comment: Those are all good definition of critical point which depend on context. For example definition MAG only works when there is a spontaneous magnetization. So each definition makes sense only In specific context. As a consequence the first two questions don't really make sense because T_Mag, for example, simply doesn't exist if the system doesn't have spontaneous magnetization. But the system could still undergo a critical phase. I would say the more general definition of critical point is a point where the free energy is non-analytic.